# How do I display contents of my mongodb database to my front end?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Basically I need to retrieve user input from my html. Use that input to search my mongoDB database via mongoose. Then retrieve and display that information to the front end. I have no idea about how to go about doing this.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. There are many blogs such as this - https://medium.com/netscape/mean-app-tutorial-with-angular-4-part-1-18691663ea96. Please go through them and come back to stackoverflow once you have a specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Retrieving data means sending Get Request to your node end point**

Since I use axios, I will recommend you to use axios as well (npm install axios if you are using react or any other framework) or you can simply copy it's script CDN

**From frontend you can simply**

```
axios.get("Your url address" + "api route address").then((response) => {
         //do whatever with your response
        }).catch(error => {
         //Do something in case of error 
       })
```

Taking a practical address, suppose I have a node server connected to mongoose running on a localhost `8000`, where my api end point looks like this (**Backend**)

Where I have imported my user schema like this

```
const User = require("./../models/userSchema.js")
const User = require("./../models/userSchema.js")

router.get("/",  async (req, res) => {
  const contactList  = await User.find({}) //coming from mongoose 
  res.send(contactList)
})
```

Through axios, my api request would be like this (**frontend**)

```
axios.get("http://localhost:8000/").then((response) => {
```

**Backend Part -> Post request**

First Define and export a mongoose Schema like this

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    address: String, 
    email: {
        type: String,
        default: "www.xyz@abc.com"
    },
    number: Number,
    OTP: Number,
    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    DateOfBirth: {
        type: String,
        default: "1/01/2001"
    },
    image: {
        type: String,
        default: "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/256/contact-icon.png"
    }, 

})


module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema)
```

Then, Hoping you have configured node using MVC pattern, import it to a route where you need to use a schema

```
const express = require("express")
const router = express.Router() 
const User = require("./../models/userSchema.js")
```

Inside that schema create an API route or end point which accepts post request (or put request)

```
  router.post("/message", async (req, res) => {
  const newMessage = new User({
     firstName: req.body.(whatever from your request contains firstName
    .....
    ......
    )}
  })
```

once you have filled the data you are getting (`req.body` contains the data) you need to save it, extending on the above route

```
 router.post("/message", async (req, res) => {
  const newMessage = new User({
     firstName: req.body.(whatever from your request contains firstName
    .....
    ......
    )}
newMessage.save().then((response) => {
if (error) {
      console.log(error)
      throw  new Error (error)
      } else {
        console.dir(responseData)
        res.send(responseData)
      }
  })
  })
```

**Frontend part**

Since I use axios, I will recommend you to use axios as well (npm install axios if you are using react or any other framework) or you can simply copy it's script CDN

Inside axios, we send post request

```
 axios.post("Your port address" + Message , object).then(response => {   
          console.log(response)
          }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error)  
          })
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bigger question to cover. Let me help you to point on some specifics.

1. Define mongo model using mongoose connector.
2. Create get route in nodejs code to handle call from client.
3. use fetch or any client http wrapper to make a call to your node server.
4. respective model or service write a model.find and return the response.